# WEC7 project (Platform Builder): touch screen display drivers issue

Tags: touchscreen, platform-builder

I am trying to create a WEC7 image with Platform Builder, starting from an example workspace (from Variscite AM33 Ev. kit). I would like to connect a capacitive tousch screen display (Ampire AM-800480SBTMQW-T00): the touch screen does not work, perhaps the touch drivers included in the workspace are not compatible with my display ones. 
In the display datasheet there is a piece of source code: where should I have to add it in order to have the touch screen working? Is there a C source file, or maybe a registry that I should modify?

Answer (score 0):

The Ampire panel is different from the one originally fitted on the Variscite board, so you will need to modify the touch PDD, i.e. the hardware-specific parts of the touch driver.

I am not familiar with the Variscite BSP, but a good place to look for the PDD would be in `C:\WINCE700\PLATFORM\<BSP>\SRC\DRIVERS\TOUCH`. For example, in the sample EVM3530 BSP the touch PDD is located in `C:\WINCE700\PLATFORM\ti_evm_3530\SRC\DRIVERS\TOUCH`. Generally, you are looking for the implementation of the functions [documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg159560%28v=winembedded.70%29.aspx).

Without going into all the details, the way the touch PDD is supposed to work is that Windows CE (or, rather, the touch *MDD*) calls `TchPdd_Init` (your code in the PDD), passing a `TCH_MDD_INTERFACE_INFO` struct. This struct contains a pointer to a callback function in the MDD (`pfnMddReportSampleSet`), which the PDD can use to report touch events.

The PDD then typically sets up a thread to handle interrupts from the touch controller, read updated touch information from the hardware, and notify the MDD using the callback.